# How to further divide this query by position (SQL)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I made a basic pivot that shows the number of NFL players from each college. I'm trying to further divide the query by position, so that position is a row headed while college is a column header. I've tried making a cte but this has not worked (I get an unrecognized name error for position). How would I solve this? Here is my SQL:

```
Select * from  
(Select collegeName,position
from NFL.Players)
PIVOT(
COUNT(position) FOR(collegeName)in('Georgia','Alabama','Florida State','Texas Tech','Texas','Michigan','Louisiana State'))
```

Comment: Have you tried COUNT(collegeName) instead of count(position)?

Comment: I have not but wouldn't that turn the query into a count of college names?

Comment: I'd be surprised. Don't have a BigQuery environment set up. But in SQL Server it seems to do what you want https://dbfiddle.uk/Mkc-5iyP